# Nested if-else in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having difficulty trying to get this nested if-else to run the way I want it to. I have files with varying numbers of rows. For clarity, ctd= the file,
y= depth, and x= density. This block works fine when the depth of the file does go to 30. However, when the depth is less than 30 I can't seem to get R to recognize the second statement instead of the first. It returns `NA` when there is a numeric value that should come back.

```
if(30&1 %in% y){
  (x[y=30]-x[y=1])/29
}else if(1 %in% y & !(30 %in% y)){
  (x[nrow(ctd)]-x[y=1])/(nrow(ctd)-1)
}
```

If I run the second part by itself like this:

```
if(1 %in% y & !(30 %in% y)){
      (x[nrow(ctd)]-x[y=1])/(nrow(ctd)-1)
}
```

It works just fine on those files. What am I doing incorrectly in the first block?

Comment: You want `all( c(30,1) %in% y)` for that first condition, I think. You can read the docs at `help("%in%")`

Comment: I tried that, but found that `all` is only needed for a vector. `&` encompasses both 1 and 30 and if you test a vector with that you will only get one logical statement back.

Comment: You're not interpreting the order of operations correctly. `30&1 %in% y` is the same as `(30) & (1 %in% y)`. When a number is evaluated in a logical statement it is true unless zero so 30 is like true and we have `TRUE & 1 %in% y` or just `1 %in% y`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.